# Why is my Jest test passing and then calling the function afterwards creating a TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

[Link to repo on GitHub](https://github.com/bbenefield89/RootCodingChallenge)

Writing tests using Jest and while testing a specific function, `createDriversRecordsHash`, I can get the test to pass no problem but then it returns with a `TypeError`. The function takes a string of drivers as an argument and the only reason I can see this error happening is if someone were to call the function without passing a string.

Here you can see the test passes just fine but after the tests complete the `createDriversRecordsHash` function is called and it can't read `split` of `undefined` where `undefined` would be the `driverRecordsFileData` (the argument). How do I prevent this from happening?

[image]

If I place a `return console.log(driverRecordsFileData)` at the beginning of the function, just to see what `driverRecordsFileData` is I then get:

[image]

## Test

```
import { createDriversRecordsHash } from './main'

describe('Main.js', () => {
  test('createDriversRecordsHash', () => {
    let driverRecordsData = 'Driver Dan\n'
    driverRecordsData += 'Driver Alex\n'
    driverRecordsData += 'Driver Bob\n'
    driverRecordsData += 'Trip Dan 07:15 07:45 17.3\n'
    driverRecordsData += 'Trip Dan 06:12 06:32 21.8\n'
    driverRecordsData += 'Trip Alex 12:01 13:16 42.0'

    const hardCodedDriverRecordHash = {
      "Alex": {
          "__driverName": "Alex",
          "__milesPerHour": 34,
          "__totalDrivingDistInMiles": 42,
          "__totalDrivingTimeInHrs": 1.25,
        },
        "Bob": {
          "__driverName": "Bob",
          "__milesPerHour": 0,
          "__totalDrivingDistInMiles": 0,
          "__totalDrivingTimeInHrs": 0,
        },
        "Dan": {
          "__driverName": "Dan",
          "__milesPerHour": 47,
          "__totalDrivingDistInMiles": 39,
          "__totalDrivingTimeInHrs": 0.833333333333333,
        },
      }

    const driverRecordHash = createDriversRecordsHash(driverRecordsData)
    expect(driverRecordHash).toEqual(hardCodedDriverRecordHash)
  })
})
```

## Function being tested

```
export function createDriversRecordsHash(driverRecordsFileData) {
  return driverRecordsFileData.split('\n').reduce((acc, nxt) => {
    nxt = nxt.split(' ')
    const [command, driverName, ...rest] = nxt

    if (command === 'Driver') {
      acc[driverName] = new Driver(driverName)
    }
    else {
      let distInMiles = Math.round(Number(rest[2]))
      acc[driverName].setTotalDrivingDistInMiles(distInMiles)
      acc[driverName].setTotalDrivingTimeInHrs(rest)
      acc[driverName].setMilesPerHour()
    }

    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that when you do import { createDriversRecordsHash } from './main', it runs all the code in `main.js` as part of preparing the import.

So `getDriverRecords().then(data => console.log(data))` runs asynchronously, since getDriverRecords returns a promise and uses fs.readFile, an async function. In this scenario, you haven't called it via a CLI, so `process.argv[2]` is undefined, and then `data` is undefined, and so then undefined gets passed to `createDriversRecordsHash` on line 20, which then generates the error.

Because the jest test runs synchronously, it completes the passing test and the error is thrown only after the promise resolves.